# Accessing local IP of network adapter from another one

Tags: networking, windows-7

I have 2 network adapters.
Wired and wireless adapters.
I have different real IPs for both of them.
Local IPs: 192.168.100.15 and 192.168.44.10 (for example)

My default adapter is 192.168.100.15 but via ForceBindIP I open firefox from second network adapter (192.168.44.10).

I have web server on 192.168.100.15 but when I try to achieve http://192.168.100.15 through firefox I can't.

So how can I access the local IP of one an adapter from another network adapter?

Comment: what is the subnet mask used by your network adapters? do you have a dhcp server serving the ip addresses?

Comment: It's 255.255.255.0 for both of them. 192.168.100.15 from first network adapter is static, 192.168.44.10 from second adapter is from dhcp.

Comment: I see. see my answer. try to set your static ip to use the 192.168.44.x subnet.

Answer (score 0):

You two network, both with subnet mask of 255.255.355.0, belongs to two distinct network. Try to set your adapters to use the same first 3 set of numbers should solve your problem. eg 192.168.44.100 and 192.168.44.15